# How do i handle cache that causes delay on my website updates

Tags: google-chrome

Every time I update my web, I need to clear the browser cache before I can see my updates, if I do not clear the cache, I won't see the updates. I fear that other users won't see my updated web if they do not clear the cache. How do I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

There is a nocache in the developer options! Press f12 -> got to network tab -> check disable cache